# Load and transform data from multiple files

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty very to haskell. I have some data crunching to do and figured I'd do it in haskell. In essence I take the contents of multiple files, transform them and store the new output in one file. Each file gets transformed into a list of numbers. I then need to transpose the lists before saving the output. I have the following:

```
main = do
    allFiles <- getDirectoryContents inputDir
    contents <- readFile (validFiles allFiles !! 1)
    let activeCompanies = getMonthRow contents
    print $ activeCompanies

getMonthRow :: String -> [String]
-- returns the needed data from the file

validFiles :: [String] -> [String]
-- removes invalid files from the list of filenames
```

This works, and `activeCompanies` contains a list of numbers as it should. As a proof I take only the first file in the `validFiles`. What I'd like to do is read in the data from all the files and store them in one big list.  It'll be something like this

```
[["1","2","3"],["2","3","4"],["4","5","6"]]
where each sublist is the `activeCompanies` list I retrieved from one file
```

The reason for this is that I need to transpose the data before storing it all in an output file (ie multiple input files, one output file).

How can I achieve this? One thought I had is that for each file I could write the list to the output file with one element per row, and then update each line in the output file as I read the input files. However, I'm all ears at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work. It reads all files and [transposes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) the contents with `getMonthRow` mapped over it.

```
import Data.List

main = do
  allFiles <- getDirectoryContents inputDir
  contents <- mapM readFile $ validFiles allFiles
  print $ transpose $ map getMonthRow contents
```

Comment: The last line should be `print $ transpose $ map getMonthRow contents` but other than that this worked wonderfully.

Comment: This doesn't *first* read all files. `readFile` is lazy input. If `getMonthRow` is also sufficiently lazy, this should be able to stream all the files in parallel while writing the output, as long as you don't run out of open file descriptors. Which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It loops through all valid files, reads them, and applies `getMonthRow`.

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
    allFiles <- getDirectoryContents inputDir
    bigList <- forM (validFiles allFiles) (fmap getMonthRow . readFile)
    print bigList
```

More in detail, `forM` in this case takes a list of type `[String]`, and a function of type `String -> IO [String]`. Its result makes `bigList` a `[[String]]`.

The `fmap getMonthRow . readFile` snippet is equivalent to the auxiliary function

```
readMonthRow :: String -> IO [String]
readMonthRow s = do
     wholeFile <- readFile s
     return (getMonthRow wholeFile)
```